# Selecting transistor base resistor for LED switching application based on datasheet

Tags: transistors, led, pwm, raspberry-pi, datasheet

I have been trying to understand how to read a transistor datasheet properly, and to apply the ratings into my circuit to be able to calculate the needed resistor on the base leg.

I have a basic setup where my collector pin contains a 12V/3A LED supplied by a 12V power supply.

I am trying to control the power with a Raspberry Pi 4 Model b from the base leg.

What is needed to be known is that Raspberry's GPIO pin (3.3V logic) can handle 16mA at most, therefore, I employed a Darlington NPN transistor - [BDX53C](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bdx53c-d.pdf) - to safely dim/amplify the LED's brightness with a PWM control.

I tried to get the basics of calculating the right amount of resistor to be able to safely control the environment without harming either the transistor or the Pi. I saw in [this specific discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100762/control-5v-dc-motor-with-arduino) and other various similar topics on the internet that people either calculate the potential difference in the base leg as 0.7V if it is a regular NPN or PNP transistor or 1.3 ~ 1.5V if it is a Darlington transistor.

Somehow, I couldn't find those values anywhere neither in my transistor datasheet nor in others. So my questions would be:

1. Is the \$h_{FE}\$ value only needed to calculate the right resistor value in a setup? If not, are 0.7V and 1.5V potential differences nothing but a myth? Which variables represent those values in a transistor datasheet?
2. What do the \$V_{CE(SAT)}\$ and \$V_{BE(SAT)}\$ variables represent in a transistor setup? Additionally, how can I find more specific values of them if they are needed, for instance, \$I_{C}=3A\$ but \$I_{B}=8mA\$?
3. How can I assure myself that a transistor is suitable for my setup? For instance, how can I determine whether a BDX53C would properly yield qualified performance considering 12V/3A LED PWM control?
4. I observed that people use the transistors in their setup as a switch most of the time. Therefore, they make a certain calculation about the base resistors. Do I need to take something extra into account as I would want to use the power between 60-100% at different times using a PWM configuration in my Pi?

Comment: Please update your question to include the logic voltage of your R Pi so we don't need to look it up. It makes a difference for the base resistor calculation.  A link to the LED datasheet would be helpful too.

Comment: @Theodore GPIO pin supplies 3.3V with 16mA maximum. LED does not have a datasheet, unfortunately. It is from a local store which I had to make customization on it. Nevertheless, I can provide that it works under 12V/3A.

Comment: You don't need a Darlington BJT for LED switching/dimming, especially not when dealing with 3.3V logic - simple 2N2222 or 2N3904 would suffice. Use appropriate current limiting resistor for the LED - taking into the account VBE, and use a base resistor to limit the current draw from the MCU to some safe level.

Comment: @George I am not sure whether I'm looking at the right datasheet but according to the [2N2222](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1129135/SEMTECH/2N2222/1) and [2N3904](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1114626/Motorola/2N3904/1), the \$I_{C}\$ should be 600mA and 200mA at maximum, respectively. How am I supposed to control 3A with such a specification?

Comment: Oh, I may have misread the power requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PWM the transistor is going to be used as a switch, it's either in saturation or cutoff. In the datasheet saturation specifications they are showing the base current as being 1/250th of the collector current, so 12 mA for an IC of 3 A.

Looking at this graph:[image: Vbe(sat) for Ic = 3A]

that puts Vbe(sat) at just over 2 V, so subtract that from the voltage out of your Pi and divide by 12 mA to get the resistance for the base resistor.

From this graph:[image: Vce(sat) for Ic = 3A]

Vce(sat) is about 1.3 V, so subtract that from the supply voltage to get the voltage available to the LED.

Comment: The Vce(sat) of the darlington is 2.5V max at 3A. Then the "12V" LED gets only 9.5V and might not light or might be very dim. Please post the datasheet for the LED.

Comment: @Audioguru True, they'd probably be better off with a MOSFET for this application.

Comment: @Audioguru I do not have a datasheet for the LED, unfortunately. It works by 12V and according to that, I measured a 3A load from my power supply. What if I provide 14.5V to my collector's leg so that I compensate for the 2.5V drop while the saturation?

Comment: @GodJihyo may I ask which graph you looked at for the \$V_{BE(SAT)}\$ value? Additionally, is the 12mA value the threshold value for the transistor needed to be exceeded to be able to saturate?

Comment: Ah... I think I mixed up the Vbe and Vce graphs. Answer edited.
Looking at it again it looks like Audioguru used the Vbe(sat) value instead of Vce(sat) so you'd only lose 2.0V to the LED instead of 2.5V. Of course those are the max values, both of those are lower in the graphs which should be more typical values, so you might want to figure on Vce(sat) being 1.3V.  I would try it with 12V and see how it works, it might be fine,
As for the 12mA value, that's the value they tested Vce(sat) at, and the graph says Ic = 250 * Ib.

Comment: Quote: "The base current needs to be enough to drive it into saturation,". The base current cannot "drive" the BJT into saturation. In contrary: A large base current is an INDICATION for the state of saturation. Saturation means, that there is a base voltage which is large enough to open not only the B-E junction but also base-collector pn junction. That is the reason for the large current into the base. And the design must ensure that this current can go through the base resistor into the BJT.

Comment: @GodJihyo tbh, the values shared in the datasheet are a bit confusing. They don't truly match. On one side, they share \$h_{FE}\$ as 750, then, in Figure 2, they take it as 250. Besides this, I can't see a graph for the transistor behavior under the 12V/3A circumstance.

Comment: @LvW I also wonder where this minimum current is stated for the base in the datasheet. There are \$I_{B}\$ values that belong to testing rates but couldn't find the minimum need for my setup.

Comment: @Nihat, why should they specify a minimum of current? Current is the RESULT of voltage - hence, a minimum/maximum/typical value for the voltage makes sense.

Comment: @nihat hFE will vary with collector current, it will be lower when the transistor is saturated than when it is operating in it's linear region. The data sheet is taking Ib = Ic/250 as it's test point for saturation. I've added the graphs to my answer.

Comment: @GodJihyo thanks for the effort. appreciated it. Your explanations brought another question to my mind. Is it necessary to exceed 12mA to fully saturate the transistor? My concern is that there would be very little space for my Pi's maximum current rating (16mA) if I would put such a resistor value. From various documents, I saw that people take \$h_{FE}\$ value into account which is specified as 750 in my case but you derive it from Figure 2. When I calculate by that value I end up with 4mA (3A from the LED divided by 750) in the base leg. Which is more reliable you think?

Comment: @Nihat, remeber the definition for saturation: The voltage Vce is so small (0.2...0.3 volts) that not only the B-E junction but also the B-C junction is forward biased. This RESULTS in a pretty large base current - however, it is not a current that brings a BJT into the saturation state. It is the voltage developed by the current across the collector resistor which is responsible.

Comment: @LvW I understand this. But still, I need to know which \$h_{FE}\$ value I should rely on since it makes a difference on the \$I_{B}\$ which is important for me not to harm my controller.

Comment: hFE is used only when a transistor or darlington IS NOT SATURATED. The hFE spec has a fairly high Vce. Most transistors have a maximum Vce saturation voltage when the base current is 1/10th the collector current even if the non-saturated hFE is very high. A darlington has a base current of 1/250th the collector current for its guaranteed max VCE when saturated.

Comment: @Audioguru I just found time to see the working principles of the transistor in practice. Due to the limit of the power supply I have, the current through the LEDs could only reach 2.6A, but the Vce value was 1.31V as in the graph. But even though, I was having a 470R in my base leg, I measured the current around 60mA. That only confused me a little bit but other than that, I feel alright :) Do you think that matches the graph in the datasheet?

Comment: The graph shows a device with "typical" specs. Some devices have better specs and some devices have worse specs.
I design circuits so all passing devices work, not just the "typical and better" ones.